# search for duplicate photos

Tags: search, delete, perl, duplicate-files

I have photos, in folder A, they also exist, in folders B and C. They have the same filenames. How to search for them and delete them from folder A? A perl script or something would be ideal since I don't like to download a software for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
find . -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec echo mv -v "$destdir/{}" "$ToDelete"/ \;
```

#### How to use?

**Step 1:** Make a temporary directory to moving duplicate files into that:

```
ToDelete=/tmp/ToDelete; mkdir -p "$ToDelete"
```

**Step 2:** Set `destdir` to your FolderA directory which we want to delete duplicate photos from there.

```
destdir=/path/to/FolderA
```

**Step 3** cd to your first source directory(FolderB) and run the command

```
cd /path/to/FolderB

find . -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec echo mv -v "$destdir/{}" "$ToDelete"/ \;
```

**Step 4:** Now cd to your next source directory(FolderC) and run again the command

```
cd /path/to/FolderC

find . -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec echo mv -v "$destdir/{}" "$ToDelete"/ \;
```

Ok. Now if you test the command and see the result, so remove the `echo` command to moving the duplicate photos into `/tmp/ToDelete` directory.

See the test below:

```
$ ls ~/FolderA    
  1.jpg  2.jpg  6.jpg  7.jpg  8.jpg

$ ls ~/FolderB    
  3.jpg  4.jpg  5.jpg  7.jpg  8.jpg  9.jpg

$ ls ~/FolderC
  6.jpg  7.jpg  8.jpg  9.jpg

$ ToDelete=/tmp/ToDelete; mkdir -p "$ToDelete"
$ ls /tmp/ToDelete/
$ destdir=~/FolderA

$ cd ~/FolderB
/FolderB$ find . -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec mv -v "$destdir/{}" "$ToDelete"/ \;
  ‘/home/Fischer/FolderA/./8.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/ToDelete/8.jpg’
  removed ‘/home/Fischer/FolderA/./8.jpg’
  ‘/home/Fischer/FolderA/./7.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/ToDelete/7.jpg’
  removed ‘/home/Fischer/FolderA/./7.jpg’

/FolderB$ cd ~/FolderC
/FolderC$ find . -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec mv -v "$destdir/{}" "$ToDelete"/ \;
  ‘/home/Fischer/FolderA/./6.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/ToDelete/6.jpg’
  removed ‘/home/Fischer/FolderA/./6.jpg’

/FolderC$ ls /tmp/ToDelete/
  6.jpg  7.jpg  8.jpg

/FolderC$ ls -l ~/FolderA
  1.jpg  2.jpg

/FolderC$ C00L ;)
```

#### And How it works?

When you switch into your FolderB or FolderC and you run [find command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1posix.html), so you are looking for any file in it (`.` refer to current directory) and then with [cmp command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cmp.1plan9.html)(used to compare two files byte by byte) you compare each files(`{}`) in FolderB/FolderC with files in `destdir`(FolderA(`$destdir/{}`)) if they are the same then we move that file(from FolderA to temp directory in `/tmp/ToDelete`) with next [mv command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mv.1.html) `-exec mv "$destdir/{}" "$ToDelete"/ \;`.

Answer (score 1):

The program [findimagedupes](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) should do what you request:

> Finds visually similar or duplicate images

The program is a simple perl program and can be started from the command line - but is also available as a software package.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the program fslint

it searches for duplicates (among other things)

fslint can be downloaded in the software center. fslint has a user interface when you open the program, the first tab is about finding duplicata. you can specify the folder/folders.

more information : [user manual fslint](http://en.flossmanuals.net/fslint/ch004_duplicates/)

Comment: AU encourages [high quality answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you please elaborate how to use `fslint` to search for duplicates?

Comment: fslint can be downloaded in the software center

fslint has a user interface

when you open the program, the first tab is about finding duplicata. you can specify the folder/folders.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a small number of photos, you could use nautilus or another file manager

- go to the parent folder of A, B, C
- search for .jpg (or the file extension of your pictures: .png, .gif, ...)
- sort alphabetically (make sure to view the sourcepath of the file)
- delete the duplicate files you don't need anymore

Answer (score 0):

There are many [duplicate photo finder](https://www.duplicatephotosfixer.com/) utilities available online. Some are better than others, some are faster, some are easy to use, many are free, and some have to pay to unlock full functionality.

Perform a Google search with the best duplicate photo finder phrases to figure out what's available and find the one that suits your needs.